# Printing part of a String after split

Tags: java, android-studio

For example I have

**String test = "www/testing/how/FileName.txt";** (this is a server url)

from here... I want to print out just

**String test1 = "www/testing/how";**

so that I can create a directory of test1 and add the Filename.txt.

Can someone help?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." [Now they have two problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `lastIndexOf()`

```
String s= "www/testing/how/FileName.txt";
System.out.println(s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf('/')));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy enough to handle using a one-liner, with the help of `String#replaceAll`:

```
String test = "www/testing/how/FileName.txt";
System.out.println(test.replaceAll("/[^/]+\\.\\w+$", ""));

www/testing/how
```

The regex pattern I used targets the final path separator, and everything after it, for removal, leaving behind the output you expect.